# Shimano 105 5700 in 2019

Tags: road-bike, shimano

I want to begin with road biking as a sport and are currently trying to find a decent bike.

Some friends recommended to get the Radon R1 2019 with a complete Shimano 105 R7000 groupset.

In a bike-store I found a new no brand bike with a complete Shimano 105 5700 groupset.
It also features an aluminum frame, a carbon fork and weighs about 10.5kg for less than 300€.
Is it still relevant in 2019, as it is almost 10 years old, or is it comparable with newer Shimano Sora groupsets via trickle-down?

There seems to be a lot of myths and opinions on various groupsets, but is there some "evidence", which indicates a different performance?

Comment: 10.5kg would be heavy for an all steel 105-level bike. A couple of extra kilograms aren't that bad in itself, but they are a sign that the manufacturers skimped on everything but groupset on that bike.

Comment: Evidence is going to be hard to come by. Generally, current generation 105, Ultegra, and Dura Ace should have higher tolerances than Tiagra and below, i.e. the variations in the manufacturing processes should be lower, and the components should last longer. The thing is, I don't think any data of that sort is public. That older 105 is actually comparable to current Tiagra. From what I hear (again, opinions), current Tiagra is actually quite good!

Comment: A brand new 5700 drivetrain would work just fine - for a 10 speed, rim brake groupset. I'd think about whether the components really are new, and availability of replacement components if something breaks. I'd be very wary of a no-brand alloy frame.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus At first glance, I'd agree I'd be wary of a no-brand alloy frame. However, Radon doesn't seem to be a well-known quantity either. It looks like a German brand. I don't know what its reputation in Germany is like.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! What should I be wary off on a no-brand alloy frame? Is it more about riding comfort or durability?

Answer (score 4):

This is very much opinion based question. I'd say that 5700 is still above current day Sora and a very solid choice indeed. I'll also argue with some of the comments that 10.5kg is heavy, especially at the price point of 300 EUR. As a comparison Triban 520 RC (praised to be extremely good value alu/carbon bike for packing partial Shimano 105 groupset in 750 EUR) is 10.3kg. There are very few bikes under 9kg that cost less than 1000 EUR and probably none under 10kg for 500 EUR or less.

Actually, at this price point, this is probably way above anything else you might be able to get.